# Try and Catch laravel without $id

Tags: php, laravel, try-catch

everyone, some days ago, I asked for a possible solution for Try and Catch in a function where I pass $id, but now, I've a similar problem, now, I don't need to pass any $id, just a view, the view has a file (PDF) that is upload from the Admin Panel of my aplication, I tried that whem some admin delete the file (PDF) and an user try to visit the page of terms and conditions without any PDF uploaded, the system redirect to other page, like home; this is my code:

```
    public function terms()
  {
    try {
      $terms = Multimedia::where('multimedia_type', 'terms')->first();
      return view('terms.terms', compact('terms'));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect('/')->with('errors', 'Ha ocurrido un errror, lo sentimos');
    }
  }
```

But, when I delete the file, I got this error:

> (2/2) ErrorException
>   Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/vagrant/Code/Biblio/resources/views/terms/terms.blade.php)

And the system didn't redirect to other page. If someone can help, I'll be really grateful

Comment: What code is present in terms.blade.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming from the Blade template. In this case where the file doesn't exist, it will break outside of the try catch. The PHP assumes you are passing `null` into the template.

To handle this, you can do the following:

```
if($terms) {
    return view('terms.terms', compact('terms'));
} else {
    return redirect('/')->with('errors', 'Ha ocurrido un errror, lo sentimos');
}
```

Note, you can do this outside of a try catch and in the function just declare `$terms` as you already have.

Comment: This is the correct answer, thanks men, you really help me!